# Changing the elements in a string that follow a particular pattern

Tags: pandas, regex, string

So I have a list containing years. However, there are typing errors in the list. kindly check the following list.

```
list=[999.0,1006.0,1007.0,1008.0,1009.0,1010.0,1015.0,2006,2007,2008,2010,2015,2009]
```

So I want to replace the first two digits '10' with '20'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if, else in list squares

If elements in the list are strings

```
lst  = ['999.0','1006.0','1007.0','1008.0','1009.0','1010.0','1015.0','2006','2007','2008','2010','2015','2009']
    
  [x.replace('10','20') if x.startswith('10') else x for x in lst ]
```

If elements in the list are not strings

```
[str(int(x)).replace('10','20') if str(int(x)).startswith('10') else str(int(x)) for x in lst2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python `re` library you could convert the years in the list to strings and use a `re.sub` and then convert them back to `int`s like this (the inner `int()` is to remove the decimals):

```py
import re
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = int(re.sub("10([0-9]{2})", r"20\1", str(int(list[i]))))
```

list in:

```py
[999.0,1006.0,1007.0,1008.0,1009.0,1010.0,1015.0,2006,2007,2008,2010,2015,2009]
```

list out:

```py
[999, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2015, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2010, 2015, 2009]
```

If you want to convert years like `999` to `1999` as well, you could use a simple comparison as well:

```py
import re
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = int(re.sub("10([0-9]{2})", r"20\1", str(int(list[i]))))
    if list[i] < 1000: list[i] += 1000
```

list out:

```py
[1999, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2015, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2010, 2015, 2009]
```